# Translating FORTRAN function to C#

Tags: c#, fortran

I'm looking at the below fortran code that calculates a moving average and trying to figure out if it's a trailing, centered, or forward average.

```
subroutine ma(x, n, len, ave)

integer n, len, i, j, k, m, newn
real x(n), ave(n), flen, v

newn = n-len+1
flen = float(len)
v = 0.0
# get the first average
do i = 1,len
    v = v+x(i)
ave(1) = v/flen 
if (newn>1) {
    k = len
    m = 0
    do j = 2, newn {
# window down the array
        k = k+1
        m = m+1
        v = v-x(m)+x(k)
        ave(j) = v/flen 
    }
}
return
end
```

EDIT:
I'm particularly confused because this function is called as

```
ma(x,n,np,out)
```

Where `x` is an array and `n` is equal to the length of `x` plus `2*np`. It seems that the second `do` loop would then index beyond the bounds of `x`.

EDIT 2: This is how this subroutine is called:

```
subroutine fts(x,n,np,trend,work)

integer n, np
real x(n), trend(n), work(n)

call ma(x,n,np,trend)
call ma(trend,n-np+1,np,work)
call ma(work,n-2*np+2,3,trend)
return
end
```

Comment: Since there is no reference to an external library or to a built-in magic function it can be translated to any language easily. Where do you have the problem?

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot to add the calling context. My bad.

Comment: Note I made an addition to the answer.  It is a much simplified version for C# instead of a direct translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I pieced this together correctly...

This function is returning an array of averages. (ave)

The first element of that array is determined here:

```
do i = 1,len
  v = v+x(i)
ave(1) = v/flen
```

It sums (len) number of elements and then divides by (len) - actually (flen) which is simply the int len converted to a real(think float for c#).

The following conditional actually produces 0 to many additional (ave) elements.
The number is determined by the difference between (n) and (len).

It adds each consecutive value to the previously calculated sum, then gets an average for the new total by dividing by (k) : which begins as (len + 1)

EDIT:  I made a mistake in my initial understanding of the logic.  I still have code for what I have described.  But the code actually moves a window over the input set getting average for the same number of elements each time, rather than accumulating an average for a growing input size.  I also added an updated answer at the bottom of this post.

With that in mind try this C# translation:

```
  public float[] CalcRollingAverage (float[] inputs, int beginAvg, int numInputs)
 {
  float[] averages = new float[(numInputs - beginAvg + 1)];

  float sumUpToBeginAvg = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < beginAvg; i++)
  {
      sumUpToBeginAvg += inputs[i];
  }

  averages[0] = sumUpToBeginAvg / beginAvg;

  int additionalAvgs = numInputs - beginAvg;

  if(additionalAvgs > 0)
  {
      float currentSum = sumUpToBeginAvg;
      int nextValIndex = numInputs - additionalAvgs - 1;

      for(int j = 1; j <= additionalAvgs; j++)
      {
          currentSum += inputs[nextValIndex];

          averages[j] = currentSum / (nextValIndex + 1); 
      }   

      nextValIndex++;
  }

  return averages;  
}
```

Please double check the math, there were a lot of adjustments for 0 based array in C# vs 1 based array in Fortran.

Also, the Fortran version basically used a ref parameter for averages, I instead created a new array and returned it.  Both work, but the second way is more conventional in C# I believe.

Above was as direct a translation as I could come up with.  Below is a much simplified version using more appropriate data structures.

```
  public List<float> CalcRollingAverage(List<float> inputs, int beginAvg)
  {
  List<float> results = new List<float>();

  int index = 1;
  float currentSumOfInputs = 0;

  foreach(float value in inputs)
  {
      currentSumOfInputs += value;

      if(index >= beginAvg)
      {
          results.Add(currentSumOfInputs / index);
      }

      index++;
    }

    return results;
  }
```

An update based our recent discovery of me missing some of the original logic.  This one moves the window and keeps the number of elements averaged the same:

```
public List<float> CalcRollingAverage(List<float> inputs, int windowSize)
{
    List<float> results = new List<float>();

    int index = 1;
    float currentSumOfInputs = 0;

    foreach(float value in inputs)
    {
        currentSumOfInputs += value;

        if(index == windowSize)
        {
            results.Add(currentSumOfInputs / windowSize);
            break;
        }                 
      index++;
    }

  if(inputs.Count > windowSize)
  {
      for(int i = index - windowSize + 1; i <= inputs.Count; i++;)
      {
        currentSumOfInputs = currentSumOfInputs - inputs(index - windowSize);
        currentSumOfInputs += inputs(index);
        results.Add(currentSumOfInputs / windowSize)
        index++;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The help is very appreciated. Question: this code seems to incrementally expand the range over which the average is calculated, but from my read of the fortran, that second do loop keeps the range constant - or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: `do j = 2, newn {
# window down the array
        k = k+1
        m = m+1
        v = v-x(m)+x(k)
        ave(j) = v/flen`

Comment: @A0A OH CRAP! It actually keeps the number of values it averages constant.  So instead of just adding a new element, it adds a new element and removes one from the front to keep the window the same size.  Sorry I didn't catch it before, but with the code provided you should easily be able to modify the C# to achieve that business logic.  Though I can help with those changes if you need me to.

Comment: Perfect! And yeah that's an easy change dw about it. So it seems that this is a trailing average, i.e. the average of the last `n` elements. This would imply that if you want an averages array of length `m`, you would put in an array of length `m+n`, where the first `n` points are lost. The author of the original source code, however, insists that for this to work, the input array has to be of length `m+2n`, where you lose `n` values at both ends of the array. Any idea why he may say that? I updated the original post with the call context. Thanks again!

Comment: @A0A so in this line "v = v-x(m)+x(k)" he is clearly removing 1 element from the front, while adding 1 element to the back.  He is simply sliding a window across a given number of elements.  He then pulls the average from the new total. (v) is the sum of his values.

Comment: @A0A the additional calls to the subroutines with different parameters may result in what he is saying.  My comments are limited to the scope of the subroutine.  Also, I updated the answer.